# Как прикрепить текст к низу с расширением вверх?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Ка сделать чтобы было как на картинке, чтобы в зависимости от высоты 2-ого снизу поля, 3-е снизу меняло свою позицию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.categories__items {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.categories__items > div {
    width: 210px;
    height: 290px;
    margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item__image {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: scale(1.7);
}

.item__number {
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories__items">
            <div class="categories__item1">
                <p class="item__price">$45.50</p>
                <img class="item__image" src="img/tapok.svg" alt="">
                <p class="item__male">MEN</p>
                <p class="item__name">Converse</p>
                <p class="item__number">#3247234</p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item2">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item3">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item4">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item5">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item6">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item7">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="categories__item8">
                <p class="item__price"></p>
                <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
                <p class="item__male"></p>
                <p class="item__name"></p>
                <p class="item__number"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Так третье снизу поле вроде как и меняает свое положение при добавлении блоков текста ко второму полю.  Или же вы хотите чтобы блок с текстом наоборот к верху вытягивался?

Comment: Кстати тоже верстаю этот макет;)

Comment: @midia Да, хочу чтобы вытягивались вверх, чтобы расстояние от границы до номера снизу было везде одинаковым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.categories__items {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.categories__items > div {
    width: 210px;
    height: 290px;
    margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item__image {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: scale(1.7);
}

.item__number {
    font-size: 8px;
}

.con {
    position: relative;

}

.con2 {
    position: absolute;

    bottom: -250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="categories__items">
        <div class="categories__item1">
            <p class="item__price">$45.50</p>
            <img class="item__image" src="img/tapok.svg" alt="">
            <p class="item__male">MEN</p>
            <p class="item__name">Converse</p>
            <p class="item__number">#3247234</p>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__itm2">
            <div class="con">
                <div class="con2">


                    <p class="item__price">$45.50</p>
                    <img class="item__image" src="img/tapok.svg" alt="">
                    <p class="item__male">MEN</p>
                    <p class="item__name">Converse</p>
                    <p class="item__name">Converse</p>
                    <p class="item__name">Converse</p>
                    <p class="item__name">Converse</p>
                    <p class="item__number">#3247234</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__item3">
            <p class="item__price"></p>
            <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
            <p class="item__male"></p>
            <p class="item__name"></p>
            <p class="item__number"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__item4">
            <p class="item__price"></p>
            <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
            <p class="item__male"></p>
            <p class="item__name"></p>
            <p class="item__number"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__item5">
            <p class="item__price"></p>
            <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
            <p class="item__male"></p>
            <p class="item__name"></p>
            <p class="item__number"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__item6">
            <p class="item__price"></p>
            <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
            <p class="item__male"></p>
            <p class="item__name"></p>
            <p class="item__number"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__item7">
            <p class="item__price"></p>
            <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
            <p class="item__male"></p>
            <p class="item__name"></p>
            <p class="item__number"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="categories__item8">
            <p class="item__price"></p>
            <img class="item__image" src="" alt="">
            <p class="item__male"></p>
            <p class="item__name"></p>
            <p class="item__number"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Подобавляйте и поубирайте Converse во втором блоке, как видите блок расширятся вверх.

Comment: Спасибо большое)))